# What, if any, available older versions of Linux distributions does xroach gracefully run on?

Tags: linux

I.e. how can I run xroach on a VM?

A search on RC for xroach didn't turn anything up.

xroach, as I remember it, ran under old versions of X and had a certain number of cockroaches on the root window which would run for cover if you closed, quickly moved, etc. a window they were hiding under.

Comment: Is using a VM and an old Linux version a hard requirement? From what I understand, xroach should still work under modern versions of Linux; packages are available here (https://pkgs.org/download/xroach). If it doesn't, it's probably because xroach tries to paint on the root window, but modern desktop environments tend to obscure that. You can work around that by using a virtual X server like xnest or Xephyr.

Comment: It there are issues, it would be the X server version, and possibly modern desktops trying to interfere. Did you try with the distro of your choice, but modern desktops not installed (e.g. plain fvwm as WM)?

Comment: Also you need to slow it down.  They move _fast_ on modern hardware.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just uploaded a new version of xroach to sourceforge. This version works in Gnome KDE, but also in FVWM and the like:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/xroachng/

for the bleeding edge visit:

https://www.ratrabbit.nl/ratrabbit/software/xroach_ng

Comment: Username checks out.

Comment: @Willem welcome to Unix.SE! Let me know if you’d like to get the package sponsored into Debian, I can take care of that for you.

Answer (score 6):

[`xroach`](https://github.com/interkosmos/xroach) (at least, this version, fixed for modern compilers) still works on current Linux distributions, as long as the desktop uses X and the root window is visible. Here it is running on Debian 10, with [FVWM](https://www.fvwm.org/) running the show:

[image: xroach running on Debian 10 with FVWM]

(the cockroaches are in the top-left of the screen).

To reproduce this, regardless of your current desktop (assuming all four programs are available):

```
Xephyr :20 &
DISPLAY=:20 fvwm &
DISPLAY=:20 xterm &
DISPLAY=:20 xroach &
```

If you want real “old school”, there’s no need for FVWM and XTerm:

```
DISPLAY=:20 xsetroot -gray
```

[image: xroach running on Debian 10 on a stippled background]

Most “full-blown” desktop environments hide the root window, and there’s not necessarily an easy way to disable this. In any case as desktops move to Wayland, `xroach`-style programs will stop working, and their replacements will have to be desktop extensions rather than generic X or Wayland clients.

Comment: The simplest way to get a visible root window on an out-of-the-box desktop would probably be to run an LXDE-based desktop and then run `pcmanfm --desktop-off` to reveal the root window. (You'll then need a more traditional desktop background setter, like [Nitrogen](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nitrogen).)